# Java + openCSV reading a file that contains multiple header lines

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

Is it possible using the opencsv library to read a file that contains several headers? While the values under the first heading are one object, and the values under the second heading are a separate object.

For example:

```
CENTER_LABEL,LAYOUT,TYPE,WEIGHTED_TYPE,DIFFICUTLY,HINT,INITIAL,MASK,LEFT_LABEL,LEFT_VALUE_LIMIT
,,,AUTOMATIC,,,0,,,1
COLUMN_VALUE,CORRECT,CORRECT_ID,FEEDBACK,INITIAL,OTHER,PERCENT,ROW_VALUE,SEQUENCE,
<p>c2</p>,false,,,false,false,50,<p>r1</p>,1,
<p>c1</p>,false,,,false,false,0,<p>r2</p>,0,
<p>c1</p>,false,,,false,false,0,<p>r1</p>,0,
<p>c2</p>,false,,,false,false,50,<p>r2</p>,1,
```

where line 1 is the fields of **object A**, line 2 is the value of this object. Line 3 is the fields of object B and lines 5-7 are the values of the fields of **object B**.

And so can I read this file into two different objects?